# How to Get The Text That is Being Entered Into The Console

Tags: c#, string, console

This is a bit confusing. Basically, at some point, the user might be typing something into the console, but I need to clear the console.

However, I don't want him to have to type it all over again.

How can I read what is being typed currently, before <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do.  If you want to save the information from console, you can use Console.readline(); to capture data then do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

you can read each pressed character with this. You also can to optionally disable showing characters on console by passing false:

```
Console.ReadKey(false);
```